How many entropy source measurements are needed to get X bits of entropy?
I have an entropy source and have estimated the min-entropy of each measurement to be just under 6 bits, calculated from the output. If I assume that each measurement of this entropy source is IID, how could this source be used to seed a PRNG? I remember reading that it's not as straight-forward as simply adding the entropies together. I.e. if I want 100 bits of entropy, I can't take 17 measurements and say 17*5,9 bits >= 100 bits, right? How does one know how many measurements are equivalent to how many bits of entropy?

How can you be sure that your IID assumption is correct in the first place?  Have you tested for that?

I can't be sure that it is, but it's passed the NIST IID tests and my intuition would've assumed that the output would look similar to that of an IID entropy source.

As a slight deep dive and please indulge me, that test suite characterises IIDness with a significance level $\alpha = 0.001$.  Are you comfortable with such low level (typically 0.05 in other fields), given the consequences of your secret messages being broken (type II error)?

@PaulUszak Oh interesting, I didn't know the exact confidence level of the test suite results. I'm not sure on how to best compensate for potential dependencies, do you have any thoughts? Maybe that deserves a separate question if one doesn't already exist.


If I assume that each measurement of this entropy source is IID, how could this source be used to seed a PRNG?

Actually, for a truly IID source, the obvious approach does work - if each sample gives you 5.9 bits of entropy, and you need 100 bits of entropy at the end, then you need $\lceil 100 / 5.9 \rceil = 17$ samples.  This is true both when you're using the Shannon definition of entropy, or Min Entropy.
The key part is the 'Independent' part of IID; that is, the distribution each sample is taken has no correlation (or other dependency) on any other group of samples.
That said, showing that a source is truly IID is hard (and I've heard some people claim that it was physically impossible). Typically, there is some long term drift in the physical device that affects the distribution, and that would add some (albeit not much) correlation between adjacent samples.
